# JQuery plugin typescript definition mixin

Tags: jquery, typescript, jquery-plugins, typescript-declarations

I am writing a JQuery plugin in TypeScript.

I have an implementation of a class `Foo.ts`

```
//Foo.ts
export class Foo {}
```

I have installed `@types/jquery` and the completions for that work fine.

Now I would like to declare a function onto the `JQuery` type, which I can do with a `types.d.ts` file like so:

```
//types.d.ts
interface JQuery {
     bar(): string;
}
```

This works to allow me to do

```
//Baz.ts
let result: string = $('#Baz').bar();
```

However, the return type of `bar()` is not `string` but should be `Foo`.

```
//types.d.ts
//import {Foo} from './Foo';

interface JQuery {
     bar(): Foo;
}
```

Gives me a red line under `Foo` `[ts] Cannot find name 'Foo'`. If I uncomment the import line, `types.d.ts` is happy, but then I then get an error in

```
//Baz.ts
let result: string = $('#Baz').bar();
// [ts] Property 'bar' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'.
```

It seems the definitions for `JQuery` are no longer merging. I understand that a types declaration file is not global if it has imports or exports, but then I don't know how to reference types in other files.

How can I declare an additional function on the `JQuery` type whos definition references other types?
Additionally, can this work so that when I import this module into another project the types for `JQuery` are merged correctly?

It certainly seems to me like this should be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a module system then then you must place the extension of `JQuery` in the global namespace:

```
import {Foo} from './Foo';

declare global {
    interface JQuery {
        bar(): Foo;
    }
}
```

If you are not using a module system then you don't need to use export on the `Foo` class and is should work.